# Submit Form With Both Action and Onsubmit Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

My JS is not that great so I have been fiddling with this for a while now.

I have a form which is being POST to another file when the submit button is clicked. When it is clicked I also want to show an alert then redirect the user back to a URL.

The redirecting code works just fine on a button where I call the function "onclick" like so:

```
<button onclick="test()">Return</button>
```

But I don't want to have an extra button for this...I want the form to POST then show an alert box then go to URL specified but I get not a function error from console, thanks.

```
<iframe name="noreloadhack" style="display:none;"></iframe>
<form action="http://www.example.com/test.php" onsubmit="return test();" method="post" target="noreloadhack">
```

JS:

```
 <script>
 function test() {
     alert('Hello World');
     var return_url = document.getElementById('return_url').value;
     window.location.href= return_url;
 }
 </script>
```

If it makes a difference I have the form target set to a hidden iframe as a hack to not reload page on submit (I know, not the best method). I'm pretty much using 4 form attributes here.

Comment: It is because you already posted and will be redirected to the form url, try using ajax on this (might be easier if you use jquery ajax). By using ajax you can submit the form without reloading or going into the page, and after the submission is completed, you can pass a callback function, in which in your case is a redirect.

Comment: Adrian Im POSTing to a hidden iframe so page doesnt refresh, would that still cause onsubmit to not work?

Comment: Oh i see, i haven't seen that one, so maybe your problem is you didn't specified the target iframe in your form tag.

`<form action="http://www.example.com/test.php" onsubmit="return test();" method="post" target="iframenamehere">`

so your form should be something like this.
`<form action="http://www.example.com/test.php" onsubmit="return test();" method="post" target="iframenamehere">
   <input type="submit" />
   <iframe name="iframenamehere">
   </iframe>
  </form>`

Comment: I did, sorry let me update question

Comment: it's okay, i build a sample fiddle for you here, sorry for the bad quality though i just copied your code cause i'm using my phone for this.
https://jsfiddle.net/n7zd1hw8/

Comment: Your answer works beautifully on jsfiddle...but I have been trying to get this to work on a simple WordPress page for the longessst while...I keep getting typeerror test is not a function...

Comment: I made a post in the WP stack because this is not working on WP: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/217630/simple-js-function-not-working

Comment: Solved with a few more lines of JS and adding script in noconflict mode (check WordPress link i posted above)

Answer (score 0):

I have some old code that I used to solve a similar situation. Where I wanted to submit a form but not reload the page, here it is. Since there were only 4 input fields I just grabbed the values using jquery.

Javascript:

```
 function processForm() {
        var teamMembers=new Array();
        console.log($("#"));
        var schoolName=$("#schoolname").val();
        var teamMembers=new Array();
        teamMembers.push($("#contestant1").val());
        teamMembers.push($("#contestant2").val());
        teamMembers.push($("#contestant3").val());
        $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "php/register.php",
                data: { schoolname: schoolName, teammembers:teamMembers.toString()}
            })
            .done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Your team is now registered " + msg );
                $('#register').hide();
                location.reload();
            });
        // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
        // default being reloading the page
        return false;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<form id="registration_form" onsubmit="return processForm()" method="POST">
<p style="margin:0px;">School Name:</p>
<input type="text" id="schoolname" name="schoolname" autocomplete="off" class="input" required>
<hr>
<p style="margin:0px;">Contestants</p>
<div id="teammembers">
    <input type="text" id="contestant1" name="contestant1" autocomplete="off" class="input" required>
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" id="contestant2" name="contestant2" autocomplete="off" class="input" required>
    <p></p>
    <input type="text" id="contestant3" name="contestant3" autocomplete="off" class="input" required>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="registered">
```